# Quale è l'equivalente della parola inglese "pittance"?

Tags: nouns

Ho tradotto "miseria", ma non credo che sia questa la traduzione giusta.

Answer (score 4):

Il [vocabolario Sansoni](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_inglese/Inglese/P/pittance.shtml) dà come possibili traduzioni

1. (small allowance) miseria, inezia, niente
2. (meagre remuneration) miseria, stipendiuccio, quattro soldi, tozzo di pane

Tralascio il significato storico di “offerta per il vitto comunitario”.

L'esempio sul dizionario Oxford è *he paid his workers a pittance*, che si può tradurre

> pagava i suoi operai una miseria

In questo senso, *miseria* è usato in modo figurato: tanto poco che è lo stesso che essere in miseria.

Potrebbe anche essere

> pagava i suoi operai quattro soldi

a seconda del contesto.

Comment: Ma non si dovrebbe dire "pagava *ai* suoi operai una miseria"? È che il doppio complemento oggetto mi sembra abbastanza angleggiante. Poi magari boh.

Comment: @Lynn La vedo come una locuzione avverbiale al posto di “poco”.